# Firebase push notification delimiter in [ console ]

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications, firebase-console

can we use new line delimiter (\n) in Firebase push notification message for multiple lines instead of using  **notificationObject.setStyle()** method.

Comment: Why don't you give it a try?

Comment: hey Frank van Puffelen thats cool man i like ur answer